# FXML will not create charts except for pie chart

Tags: fxml, linechart

I'm using Java 20.0.1 in Netbeans 18 on a Mac Notebook running OS Ventura.
When I try to create an XYChart inFXML I get a message "Instances of JavaFX.scene.chart.XYChart cannot be created by FXMLLoader". I get the same message for all xy-type charts, although it will allow a pie chart. All the FXML tutorials I've seen give examples of creating XYCharts, LineCharts, etc, using FXML.
Any suggestions?

Defined XYChart, and a LineChart in FXML, but get the message mentioned above.

PROBLEM RESOLVED. It turns out that, even though LineChart, xAxis and yAxis are flagged as errors, the procedure works. The chart is created OK!